# Quarkus saving entity with OffsetDateTime without offset/timezone

Tags: java, postgresql, vert.x, quarkus, reactive-postgresql-client

I have a **Quarkus** application where I persist data using **Vert.x Reactive PostgreSQL Client**.

Here ist the entity bean to be persisted:

```
public class SomeEntity {
  public Long id;
  public Integer f1;
  public Boolean f2;
  public SomeType f3;
  public OffsetDateTime f4;
  ...
```

Problem is the `f4` field with type `OffsetDateTime`. Before persisting, It has the value of `2020-09-11T19:07:46.822828+02:00` with the offset `+02:00` for `Berlin GMT+2`

When this record is persisted into PotgreSQL I see the value (in pgAdmin 4) being saved as `2020-09-11 17:07:46.822828+00` (in UTC without the offset). When I retrieve it back, the offset is gone.

*I would like to retrieve this back with the timezone offset.*

Here is the code snippet I use for persisting entities:

```
@QuarkusTest
public class SomeEntityRepositoryTest {

  static final Duration TIMEOUT = Duration.ofSeconds(2);

  @Inject
  Pool client;

  private Long idToGet;

  @BeforeEach
  public void initDatabase() {
    idToGet = createOne(new SomeEntity(null, 17983,
        false, SomeType.values()[0],
        OffsetDateTime.now()));
  }


  protected SomeEntity from(Row row) {
    return new SomeEntity(row.getLong("id"),
        row.getInteger("f1"),
        row.getBoolean("f2"),
        SomeType.valueOf(row.getString("f3")),
        row.getOffsetDateTime("f4"));
  }

  protected Long createOne(SomeEntity someEntity) {
    return client.preparedQuery("INSERT INTO SOME_ENTITY (f1, f2, f3, f4) "
        + "VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) "
        + "RETURNING id, f1, f2, f3, f4")
        .execute(Tuple.of(someEntity.f1,
            someEntity.f2,
            someEntity.f3.toString(),
            someEntity.f4))
        .map(RowSet::iterator)
        .map(iterator -> iterator.hasNext() ? iterator.next() : null)
        .map(this::from)
        .map(inserted -> inserted.id)
        .await()
        .atMost(TIMEOUT);
  }
```

Here is the DB Create script:

```
CREATE TABLE SOME_ENTITY (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
  f1 integer, 
  f2 boolean, 
  f3 nvarchar, 
  f4 timestamptz
)
```

Those are the dependencies from my `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation enforcedPlatform("io.quarkus:quarkus-bom:1.7.3.Final")
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy'

    testImplementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5'
    testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured'

    implementation "io.quarkus:quarkus-reactive-pg-client"
    implementation "io.quarkus:quarkus-vertx"
    implementation "io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy"
    implementation "io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jackson"
    implementation "io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-mutiny"
    implementation "io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll"
    implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3"
    implementation "io.quarkus:quarkus-liquibase"
    implementation "io.quarkus:quarkus-jdbc-postgresql"
}
```